# Python won't run in bash but will run in cmd

Tags: python, bash

If I execute my python script on the command line for windows it runs perfectly but when I run it on bash it just keeps waiting for another line but if I try other commands such as `python --version` it shows: `Python 2.7.10`.

The command I'm running is:

```
python Run.py
```

Run.py contains:

```
print 'This is a test'
```

The bash comes with Mingw64 if that helps

Comment: Where is Run.py saved?

Comment: Try to rename to `run.py` and use `python run.py`.

Comment: Python typically required that the Python source file be found in the path or you provide a relative or full path.

So unless you are in the same directory in Bash as Run.py, or Run.py is in /usr/local/bin, or similar, it cannot find Run.py and therefore won't run.

Comment: I'm running this on Windows using Git Bash. It does this http://prntscr.com/9g6sxk I kept pressing enter to see if it would run but it wouldn't.

Comment: Name is not the issue, I've tried the above with python 2.7.10 and Run.py and works fine.

Comment: Is there a feature like `strace` you can use on windows?  That should help us understand what it's doing.

Comment: @Brain Cain It loads at lot of DLLs and then freezes up. I could post the results if needed.

Comment: ...you could also, of course, just run your copy of Git Bash in the standard Windows terminal rather than the fancy one it shipped with.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a known bug in MSys2, which provides the terminal used by Git Bash.](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/32/) You can work around it by running a Python build without ncurses support, or by using [WinPTY](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/), used as follows:

> To run a Windows console program in mintty or Cygwin sshd, prepend console.exe to the command-line:
>
> ```
> $ build/console.exe c:/Python27/python.exe
> Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> 10 + 20
> 30
> >>> exit()
> ```

The [prebuilt binaries for msys](https://github.com/downloads/rprichard/winpty/winpty-0.1.1-msys.zip) are likely to work with Git Bash. (Do check whether there's a newer version if significant time has passed since this answer was posted!).

Comment: bash: build/console.exe: No such file or directory

Comment: That's an example using the WinPTY console. You need to download and install it; follow the link. (And, of course, use an invocation appropriate to the binary's actual location or status as part of your PATH).

Comment: Console crashes as soon as I click saying "msys.dll is missing".

Comment: ...an error which means exactly what it says: The binary you installed is compiled against a different msys than you have installed.

Comment: Huh? `python foo` -- which you said you were doing -- doesn't look at the shebang at all; only `./foo` does that. And on reasonable platforms (ie. not Windows), shebangs are completely awesome; they mean we don't need crap like filename extensions for executables to describe to the operating system how they should be invoked.